# passing a theorem name using ntheorem

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

I'm looking for a way to style a theorem as shown [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=10678).

[image]

The code there works if I want the theorem number in the heading box, but I also want to be able to pass a custom theorem name to add to that heading box. The optional argument seems to be showing up as part of the #1, so how do I separate it so that I can put it elsewhere?

The code I'm currently using ([from the same link given above](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=10678))

```
\usepackage{graphicx,textpos, a4wide}
\usepackage{helvet, amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[framed, amsthm]{ntheorem}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{empty}
\newcommand{\thmbox}[1]{
  \tikzstyle{thmbox} = [rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, fill=gray!20, inner sep=15pt, drop shadow={fill=black, opacity=.5}]%
  \tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=white, text=black, rectangle, rounded corners, draw= black]%
  \noindent%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node [thmbox] (box){%
      \begin{minipage}{.91\textwidth}%
        \textit{#1}%
      \end{minipage}%
    };%
  \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {\textbf{Theorem \thetheorem}%
    };%
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\def\theoremframecommand{\thmbox}
\newshadedtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

And in the body:

```
\begin{theorem}[abc]
Hello
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: Example four of the file [mdframed-example-tikz.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I think that's an answer :)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Wouldn't it be better to use typewriter type and the listings option `columns=fullflexible` in the source code? As they are it's impossible to copy-paste the code (and it's unreadable).

Comment: @egreg: I will change the settings of `listings`. You are completely right.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel An answer would be nice. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of the comments I created an approach.

The important part of the code is the redefinition of `\mdfcreateextratikz`. The package provides this command to put extra material somewhere. The coordinates `O` and `P` are used internal. In the file `md-frame-1.mdf` you can find their meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{theorem}
\renewcommand\thetheorem{Theorem~\arabic{theorem}}
\makeatletter
\mdf@dolist{\mdf@do@stringoption}{%
    {theoremtitle=={}}%
}
\renewrobustcmd\mdfcreateextratikz{%
      \node[anchor=west,rounded corners,draw,thick,shading=axis,left color=blue!20,xshift=1cm,minimum height=.7cm,minimum width=2cm] at (P-|O) 
              {~\mdf@frametitlefont{\thetheorem}%
                  \ifdefempty{\mdf@theoremtitle}%
                  {~}%
                  {:~\mdf@theoremtitle~}%
              };
}
\makeatother
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
outerlinewidth=1pt,
innerlinewidth=0pt,
roundcorner=2pt,
linecolor=black,
shadow=true,
tikzsetting={shading=axis,top color=gray!20},
innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
needspace=3\baselineskip,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
settings={\global\stepcounter{theorem}},
}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]
{\begin{mdframed}[style=theoremstyle,theoremtitle={#1}]\relax}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Title of the Theorem]
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]